# ie8 slow script message for jquery loop / .each

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, performance

In ie8 I the following message is being thrown

"a script on this page is causing internet explorer to run slowly"

This occurs when changing a select box triggering the following code, I am aware it would be better to do this with php but unfortuantly that's not an option.

The code is showing events passed on the venue chosen from a dropdown. When a venue is selected all events not at that venue are hidden.

The page the code is running on is http://sussexpast.co.uk.blueplanetdns.com/events

Thanks

```
jQuery(function($) {

    function hideMonths(){
        var months = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
        for( var i = 0; i < months.length; i++ ){
            //alert(months[i]);
            $('.events-list .post:visible .event-month:contains('+months[i]+')').not(':first').css('visibility','hidden');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        hideMonths();
    });

    $('.event-location-filter select').change( function() {
        var selectedProperty = $(this).val();
        //alert(selectedProperty);
        $('.post').each( function(){
            $(this).show()
            var eventProperty = $(this).find('.venue a').text();
            //alert(eventProperty);
            if( selectedProperty == 'Select a location' ){
                $(this).show()
                hideMonths();
            }
            else{
                if( eventProperty !== selectedProperty ){
                    $(this).hide()
                    $('.events-list .event-month').css('visibility','visible');
                    hideMonths();
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What does `$('.post').length;` show?

Comment: You are calling `hideMonths();` for *each* `.post` element.  Try calling that *outside* the `.each`.  Or, try to call `hideMonths();` using `setTimeout`.  That'll give the browser a second to catch up before it has to call more functions: `setTimeout(hideMonths, 0)`;`.

Comment: Also good thoughts, will come in handy I expect, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache most of the selector so that the entire dom isn't searched on each iteration.

```
function hideMonths(){
    var months = new Array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec');
    var $eventMonths = $('.events-list .post:visible .event-month').not(':first');
    for( var i = 0; i < months.length; i++ ){
        //alert(months[i]);
        $eventMonths.filter(':contains('+months[i]+')').css('visibility','hidden');
    }
}
```

I also see no reason for this to be done for each post, instead do it after the `.each`.

```
    $('.post').each( function(){
        $(this).show()
        var eventProperty = $(this).find('.venue a').text();
        //alert(eventProperty);
        if( selectedProperty == 'Select a location' ){
            $(this).show()
            //hideMonths();
        }
        else{
            if( eventProperty !== selectedProperty ){
                $(this).hide()
                $('.events-list .event-month').css('visibility','visible');
                //hideMonths();
            }
        }
    });
    hideMonths();
```